# place holder property is not resolved

Tags: java, spring

I'm using `@Configuration` and set a property `ehCacheConfig` with `@Value` annotation:

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {    
    @Value("${configPath}")
    private Resource ehCacheConfig;   
}
```

But when running the project error occurs as below. As the error indicates that the placeholder-property `configPath` is not resolved by the spring container. Can anyone tell me why?

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/${configPath}]
>         org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
>         org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerUtils.parseConfiguration(EhCacheManagerUtils.java:107)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `PropertySource` to load `configPath`'s value from there:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
public class CacheConfig {    

    @Value("${configPath}")
    private Resource ehCacheConfig;   

}
```

**app.properties**:

```
configPath: /home/[...]/myConfig.xml
```

Comment: I add the properties file in <context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" location="classpath*:base.properties" />, I guess this can make it like using PropertySource

Comment: Can you post the content of base.properties?

Comment: configPath=classpath:ehcache.xml
authenticationCacheName=authenticationCache
authorizationCacheName=authorizationCache

Comment: I just tried the same and it works fine. Can you remove `ignore-resource-not-found="true" ` and see if it shows some error on startup?